# How to call grandparent function of a class in extjs?

Tags: javascript, extjs, scope, extjs4

I have issues understanding scopes in javascript.Let's suppose i have the following code:

```
 Ext.define('MA.controller.user',{
   extend : 'Ext.app.Controller',
   editUser:function(){},
   updateUser : function() {
     Ext.Ajax.request({
       url : './editall',
       callback : function(options, success, response) {
         this.editUser();
       }
     })
   }//eof init
 })//eof class
```

As you can see, this.editUser() is nested into Ext.Ajax.request and updateUser

this.editUser() will return undefined.How can i call editUser inside callback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a scope issue. In the updateUser method the scope is the controller,so to call the editUser inside the callback just add the scope to the ajax request

```
Ext.define('MA.controller.user',{
 extend : 'Ext.app.Controller',
 editUser:function(){},
 updateUser : function() {
   //here this refers to the controller
   Ext.Ajax.request({
     url : './editall',
     scope: this, // add the scope as the controller
     callback : function(options, success, response) {
       this.editUser();
     }
   })
 }//eof init
 })//eof class
```